# Launching OS X application in screen center

Tags: macos, cocoa

This seems like a very basic question, but I couldn't find the answer anywhere. How do I launch my non-resizable OS X application window in the center of the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you select your top level window, the Size Inspector will show you a screen similar to this

[image: Size Inspector]

You can then drag the representation of your window to where you want it to be positioned when launched, or set the specific coordinates.

Comment: That was it, thank you very much! I changed the 'Proportional Horizontal' dropbox to 'Center Horizontally' and did the same for 'Center Vertically'.

Answer (score 2):

You can choose the center position for the window in Interface Builder by choosing the size inspector. Otherwise you can call [window center] in applicationDidFinishLaunching